# Python add ons i.e. spaCy and sciSpaCy

Tags: python, pycharm, spacy

I am currently trying to import in scispaCy and spaCy along with other packages into PyCharm to use for a project i am working on.

Do I need to find some way to import them in as a library or is there some other way that i can make use of them?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

These are Python packages that you can install in a new, clean Python environment:

```
python -m venv .env
.env\Scripts\activate 
pip install spacy
pip install scispacy
```

Now go to PyCharm - File - Settings, search for "interpreter" - gear wheel at the right - "add" - and specify the path to `Scripts\python.exe` in you new clean env, where you installed the packages. You'll now have them available to start programming!